# how to remove the UserControl in expression blend 4

Tags: expression-blend-4

I crate one UserControl name as MYUC after then i want to remove that UserControl. what should i do for that.
[image: UC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's more to this question than what's literally be asked? However I would think just deleting the UserControl you're talking about is all that would be required to remove it. Unless maybe this is a trick question somehow?